# How to make scrollable text only in one area?Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I want to make label with scrollable text that isn't the size of the whole app?
I know that to make scrollable text i have to `size_hint_y: None`.But I want to make it visible only in bottom `size_hint_y: 0.3`
Here is part of code with that label.

```
FloatLayout:
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                text: root.timesLabel
                font_size: 20
                text_size: (self.width, None)
                pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Comment: So I just want my label to start at 0.3 of y

Comment: maybe you should set size on `ScrollView` to make it only in the bottom?